# How can I print lines containing 3 words

Tags: shell, text-processing

I would like to print lines in my file which containing 3 words seperated my 2 spaces.

for example:

```
AAA BBB CCC
BB AA
CCCCCCCC
```

only `AAA BBB CCC` sshould be printed.

I already use grep for it but I cant handle the spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 awk 'NF==3' file.txt
```

this will grep line with 3 field (`NF`).

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Ev '^([^ ]* *){2}$|( .*){3}' \
<<""
aaaa 
aaaa bbbb
aaaa bbb ccc
aaaa bbb  ccc
aaaa bbb cccc dddd
```

---

```
aaaa bbb ccc
```